# Where Is My Mistake While Using If And HtmlBeginform In Asp.net Mvc4

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@if (ViewData["Ay"] == "1")
{
    <tr id="Ocak">
        <td><b>Ocak</b></td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ButcePlanlama", "Para"))
        {
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Kira, new { style = "width: 55px; height: 15px;" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Gida, new { style = "width: 55px; height: 15px;" })</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Kaydet"></input></td>
        }
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("İstatistik", "İstatistik")</td>
}
```

I take error because of using `if { }`
Why ı take this error ?

Comment: syntext error while using if and htmlbeginform together because of { } .

Comment: Can you try this: <input type="submit" value="Kaydet" /> Instead of input tag you have...I donno if it'll make a difference

Comment: I would just recommend taking out `@` symbols until you find it.  The problem might be something above the `if`...  If you have `@..code..` and then another `@` before there's a need, you will get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing table row (`</tr>`) tag:

```
@if (ViewData["Ay"] == "1")
{
    <tr id="Ocak">
        <td><b>Ocak</b></td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ButcePlanlama", "Para"))
        {
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Kira, new { style = "width: 55px; height: 15px;" })</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Gida, new { style = "width: 55px; height: 15px;" })</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Kaydet"></input></td>
        }
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("İstatistik", "İstatistik")</td>
    </tr>
}
```